# invert regex pattern in python

Tags: python, arabic, python-re

I'm trying to filter from string only the Arabic character but the next function doesn't work for me:

```py
import re

def remove_any_non_arabic_char(text):
    non_arabic_char = re.compile('^[\u0627-\u064a]')
    text = re.sub(non_arabic_char, "", text)
    print(text)
```

for example:

```
s = "Kühn xvii, 346] قال جالينوس: [1] قد اتفق جل من فسر هذا الكتا"
```

The desired output of `remove_any_non_arabic_char(s)` should be `قال جالينوس قد اتفق جل من فسر هذا الكتا` but the input stays without changes.

What should I do?

Comment: `^` should be after `[` not before it.

Comment: Great, but how to keep the white-spaces?

Comment: Add them to your exclusion set. But it is easier to grab all Arabic characters, optionally separated by a space.

Comment: Put space inside the `[]`

Comment: `'[^\\s\u0627-\u064a]'`

Comment: Use `\s` to match any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix your regex as suggested in the comments, then for a more efficient solution, you will need to expand your Unicode character selection to include all Arabic character mappings. Finally, you need to keep at least one space between Arabic words to keep the Arabic text legible:

```
import re

def remove_any_non_arabic_char(text):
    non_arabic_char = re.compile('[^\s\\u0600-\u06FF]')
    text_with_no_spaces = re.sub(non_arabic_char, "", text)
    text_with_single_spaces = " ".join(re.split("\s+", text_with_no_spaces))
    return text_with_single_spaces

text_1 = "Kühn xvii, 346] قال جالينوس: [1] قد اتفق جل من فسر هذا الكتا"

text_2 = '''
تغيّر مفهوم كلمة (أدب) من العصر الجاهلي jahili (pre-Islamic) era إلى الآن عبر
مراحل periods التاريخ المتعددة. ففي الجاهلية، كانت كلمة أدب تعني (الدعوة إلى
الطعام). وبعدها، استخدم الرسول محمد (عليه السلام) الكلمة بمعنى "التهذيب والتربية"
education and mannerism. وفي العصر الأموي، اتصلت had to do كلمة أدب
بالتاريخ والفقه والقرآن والحديث. أما في العصرالعباسي، فأصبحت تعني تعلّم الشعر
والنثر prose واتسع الأدب ليشمل أنواع المعرفة وألوانها وخصوصاً علم البلاغة واللغة.
أما في الوقت الحالي، فأصبحت كلمة أدب ذات صلة pertinent بالكلام البليغ
الجميل المؤثر that impacts في أحاسيس القاريء أو السامع.
''' 
# Isleem, N. M., & Abuhakema, G. M. (2020). Kalima wa Nagham: A Textbook for
# Teaching Arabic, Volume 2 (Vol. 3). University of Texas Press. (page 5)

print('text_1: \n', remove_any_non_arabic_char(text_1))
print('\ntext_2: \n\n', remove_any_non_arabic_char(text_2))
```

Running the code on the two texts above in Jupyter, you get:

[image]

Notice that punctuation marks shared between Arabic and English (like periods and brackets) have also been removed. To keep those, you would need to introduce more complex conditionals.